# PowerShell Not Finding a Replacing Section Character

Tags: powershell, regexp-replace, unicode-literals

I created a list and then read in data from a database table.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$RawNotes = @()
```

I read in the data to the list:

```
foreach ($TmpRow in $Datatable) {
    $RawNotes.Add($TmpRow.Notes) | Out-Null
}
```

When I try to find the items that start with a section sign and a period my match never returns true so I am not sure what I am missing.

```
 if ($RawNotes[$index] -match ("^\s*§\.")) {
    $RawNotes[$index] = $RawNotes[$index]  -replace "^\s*§\.", ""
 }
```

I tried to use the unicode equivalent [U+00A7] but that did not work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The regex works as intended `'§.foo' -replace "^\s*§\."` there is not enough information to help you

Comment: If your `$RawNotes[$index]` contains a multiline string, you'll need regex `(?m)^\s*§\.`

Comment: I am trying to delete the section sign character and a period.

What is odd, I ran the command from the terminal and it replaced the characters, but when I run it from a script it does not replace the characters.

I tried to use match to see when there is a section sign character followed by a period, but this does not match.

`if ($RawNotes[$index] -match ('^\s*§\.'))`

I read the data from a database record.  Is there something with the encoding?  The database collatoin is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS